# Macro to insert formula after last used cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to paste two different formulas in the same column (A). The reason for this is my formula references 2 different sheets so when I combine them into one formula the ranges for my cells get messed up.

So my code uses the last used row from reference sheet 1 and inserts my formula into column A. So my question is, how do I define a range that allows me to insert a formula after the last used row in column A, but the range has to stop according to the last used range in column B(in the same worksheet). So if column B stops at row 33, I want my formula to only be inserted until cell 33

This is what I have so far

```
With ThisWorkbook

With .Sheets("XYZ")
 lRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With.Sheets("ABC")
 Set rng2 = .Range("A6:A" & lRow)
     rng2.Formula = "=IF(..Very long formula..)"
```

Comment: I could be missunderstanding... So from last row + 1 in Column A until last row in Column B? So Range( ColumnA, last row +1 : Column B last row)? Is column B on the same worksheet?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52968374/edit) and show us what the expected result looks like?

Comment: Yes Wizhi, column A and B are in the same worksheet ABC

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
dim lRow as long

With ThisWorkbook

    With .Sheets("XYZ")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'or is it ....?
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    end with

    With.Sheets("ABC")
        .Range(.cells(lRow, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(0, -1)).formula = _
            "=IF(..Very long formula..)"
    end with

end with
```

Comment: Really neat answer @Jeeped. This is my interpretation... `.Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)).Formula =`, i.e. that the formula should start depending on the last row for Column A of sheet ABC and then go down to the last row of Column B... only Leena knows, see if we get more clarifications :)!

Comment: Jeeped I tried your code but got an application or object defined error. Wizhi with your code I got a type mismatch error

Comment: You get that you have to actually put in a working formula, don't you?